# Why do i see the " path " wrong

Tags: asp.net, path

i'm trying to import an excel file into my SQL table , i wrote a lot of codes but in visual studio my computer didn't see my path correctly. Example :

`string path = @"~\Uploads\File1.xls";`  here is my excel sheet its in the uploads file at my project file.

and i have this error : `'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\~\Uploads\File1.xls', is not a valid path.`

Answer (score 2):

If your path is relative to your asp.net project, use:

```
Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/File1.xls");
```

Otherwise, use the full path